# reusing the copy-and-swap idiom

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, mixins, crtp, copy-and-swap

I'm trying to put the copy-and-swap idiom into a reusable mixin:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct copy_and_swap
{
    Derived& operator=(Derived copy)
    {
        Derived* derived = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
        derived->swap(copy);
        return *derived;
    }
};
```

I intend it to be mixed in via CRTP:

```
struct Foo : copy_and_swap<Foo>
{
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "default\n";
    }

    Foo(const Foo& other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy\n";
    }

    void swap(Foo& other)
    {
        std::cout << "swap\n";
    }
};
```

However, a simple test shows that it is not working:

```
Foo x;
Foo y;
x = y;
```

This only prints "default" twice, neither "copy" nor "swap" is printed. What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe the compiler is providing his own version of `operator=` since you are missing one in your `Foo` class? Maybe you'll have to do `Foo::operator=(){return copy_and_swap();}` (pseudocode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this is one area where a macro is necessary, because of the complex rules about automatically generated copy and assignment operators.

No matter what you do, you are in either of two cases:

- You have provided (explicitly) a declaration of the assignment operator, in which case you are expected to provide a definition too
- You have not provided (explicitly) a declaration of the assignment operator, in which case the compiler will generate one if the base classes *and* non-static members have one available.

The next question, therefore, is: *Is it worth it to automate such writing ?*

Copy-And-Swap is only used for very specific classes. I do not think it's worth it.

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
 Derived& operator=(Derived copy)
```

**doesn't** declare a copy assignment operator for the base class (it has the wrong signature). So the default generated assignment operator in `Foo` will not use this operator.

Remember 12.8:

> A user-declared copy assignment operator X::operator= is a non-static
>   non-template member function of class X with exactly one parameter of
>   type X, X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&.) [Note: an
>   overloaded assignment operator must be declared to have only one
>   parameter; see 13.5.3. ] [Note: more than one form of copy assignment
>   operator may be declared for a class. ] [Note: if a class X only has a
>   copy assignment operator with a parameter of type X&, an expression of
>   type const X cannot be assigned to an object of type X.

**EDIT** don't do this (can you see why ?):

<strike>You can do:</strike>

```
template<typename Derived>
struct copy_and_swap
{
    void operator=(const copy_and_swap& copy)
    {
        Derived copy(static_cast<const Derived&>(copy));
        copy.swap(static_cast<Derived&>(*this));
    }
};
```

but you lose the potential copy elision optimization.

Indeed, this would assign twice the members of derived classes: once via `copy_and_swap<Derived>` assignment operator, and once via the derived class' generated assignment operator. To correct the situation, you'd have to do (and *not forget to do*):

```
struct Foo : copy_and_swap<Foo>
{

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& x)
    {
        static_cast<copy_and_swap<Foo>&>(*this) = x;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    // Some stateful members here
}
```

The moral of the story: *don't write a CRTP class for the copy and swap idiom*.

Comment: What if you `= delete` the compiler-generated assignment operator for Foo (assuming C++0x)?

Comment: `= delete` will forbid calling `operator=` on Foo, which is counterproductive to this.

Comment: @R. Martinho: no, it is that you force the base class to assign the members of the derived class, and the default assignment operator of the derived class will *also* assign the members. So in the end, you assign twice.

Comment: @Mike - if you have c++0x, wouldn't you just use the 'move constructor'?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inherit assignment operators as a special case, if memory correctly serves. I believe that they can be explicitly `using`'d in if you need.

Also, be careful about over use of copy-and-swap. It produces non-ideal results where the original has resources that could be re-used to make the copy, such as containers. Safety is guaranteed but optimum performance is not.

Comment: Adding the `using copy_and_swap<Foo>::operator=;` in `struct Foo`, doesn't correct the situation.  See [Alexandre C.'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080137/reusing-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/7080212#7080212).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler automatically generates a copy assignment operator for Foo, since there is none.
If you add a

```
    using copy_and_swap<Foo>::operator=;
```

to Foo you will see an error telling you about the ambiguity on g++.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't give any ambiguity.  However, the operator is still not invoked.

Comment: @André Caron: I checked it again: g++ does msvc not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could rewrite it so it looks like so:

```
template<class Derived>
struct CopySwap
{
  Dervied &operator=(Derived const &other)
  {
    return AssignImpl(other);
  }

  Derived &operator=(Dervied &&other)
  {
    return AssignImpl(std::move(other));
  }

private:
  Derived &AssignImpl(Derived other)
  {
    auto self(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
    self->swap(other);
    return *self;
  }
};
```

It'll probably all get inlined and likely won't be any slower than the original code.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer the question ([@Alexandre C. already did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080137/reusing-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/7080212#7080212)), but if you reverse the inheritance, you could make it work:

```
template<typename Base>
struct copy_and_swap : Base
{
    copy_and_swap& operator=(copy_and_swap copy)
    {
        swap(copy);
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Foo_
{
    Foo_()
    {
        std::cout << "default\n";
    }

    Foo_(const Foo_& other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy\n";
    }

    void swap(Foo_& other)
    {
        std::cout << "swap\n";
    }
};

typedef copy_and_swap<Foo_> Foo;

int main()
{
    Foo x;
    Foo y;
    x = y;
}
```